# How to properly use jquery to set a value using $.post if html value only has a name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and JS, so perhaps this is a very simple question, but I don't quite understand how to use the $.post() function for jQuery. What I'm trying to do is change a value of an input in an html file using jquery.

For example, let's say I'm trying to post to some test site, and change the value of my_data ( the name of an attribute ), which is originally at 1. 
 I figured I'd use $.post for this, so I have something like:

```
    $.post("http://test_site.com/", function(my_data) {
  $(#my_data).val(5));
});
```

However, I think that # is for the id? I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding post, or not. Any hints / points in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post is an http request that's used to change data in a server. That seems unrelated to changing the value of an input. Do you need data from another website or something?

Comment: Well, what I was trying to figure out was how to to change an input that already has some value initially, and trying to change it using another html file. Does that clarify my question?

Answer (score 0):

> You are missing `quotes` and name selector should be: `$([name='YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME'])`

Try this:

```
$("[name='my_data']").val(5);
```

Comment: So I know that I can get the proper value of my_data using $.get instead of $.post - will $.post allow me to modify the my_data value? Because it seems like I can't user window.alert to display the initial value of my_data like I was able to when I was using $.get in order to check that I had access to my_data?